# Dataframe Transformation in Python Pandas where each cell is separated by a vertical bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe where the input looks like this (just copying first row)

```
ID    Intervention Arm 1    Outcome Arm 1    Intervention Arm 2    Outcome Arm 2
340   AB | XY | PQ          LS | TU          LT                    CG | DQ
```

I want my final output to look like

```
ID      Arm    Intervention        Description    Outcome
340     1      Multi Component     AB | XY | PQ   LS
340     1      Multi Component     AB | XY | PQ   TU
340     2      LT                                 CG
340     2      LT                                 DQ
```

What is happening in the output is that it's a semi-transformation of data from wide to long where for each of the rows we take the `Outcome Arm` and split it by the separator `|` so that it becomes two separate rows. The another condition is that if there are multiple values in the `Intervention Arm`, then in the output there should be a column called `Intervention` which shall list the word `Multiple Component` if there is a `|` else it should list the intervention simply (like I have showed you in the intervention arm 2 example).

This is what I did

`df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Record ID'], var_name = 'metrics', value_name = 'values')`

and after doing some transformations and data cleaning I was able to get the first part of the output, but I was not able to the get the last column of the output. What can I do to get the output in the form that I want?

I also tried extracting the individual columns using `apply` function and using `split` method for splitting the values, but it's splitting both the interventions and outcomes columns, but I only need splits in Outcome and not Intervention which will have values depending upon the condition I listed above.

I am not an advanced user of Pandas. Please help me in this.

**Edit 1:**
If it is simpler to do, we get an output like this and then make a new column with if condition to get to my desired output

```
ID    Arm    Intervention    Outcome
340   1      AB | XY | PQ    LS
340   1      AB | XY | PQ    TU
340   2      LT              CG
340   2      LT              DQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(" Arm",'')
out=pd.wide_to_long(df,['Intervention','Outcome'],'ID','Arm',sep=' ')
out=(out.assign(Outcome=out.pop('Outcome').astype(str).str.split('|'))
        .explode('Outcome').reset_index())
out['Description']=out['Intervention'].mask(out['Intervention'].eq("LT"),'')
out['Intervention']=out['Intervention'].where(out['Intervention'].eq("LT"),'Multi Component')
```

output of `out`:

```
    ID      Arm     Intervention    Outcome     Description
0   340     1       Multi Component     LS  AB | XY | PQ
1   340     1       Multi Component     TU  AB | XY | PQ
2   340     2       LT                  CG  
3   340     2       LT                  DQ
```

Comment: I am getting this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: I inserted `.astype(str)` and both the codes work, but my output is an empty table.

Comment: @AMal updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**